# python struct unpack h or H alignment

Tags: python, struct

I am trying to unpack some raw data. (Its more than 3 bytes, but I've reduced it to this.)

I don't expect traceback in the following code. Should I? Is it problem due to alignment? As you can see 2nd is successful. (My data is unaligned. I can code around it, but should I need to?)

I am expecting (1, 770) or (1, 515) I suppose, not exception.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
(B=uchar,1,8 and H=short,2,16)

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import *  
>>> unpack('BH', '\x01\x02\x03')  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
>>> unpack('HB', '\x01\x02\x03')
(513, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, what are you really trying to unpack? 123?

Comment: Its raw binary data like 0x010203... (3 bytes) from a machine and 01 is the value of field1 and 0203 is the value of field2, etc. (
Ignacio below has fixed it anyway now. Its working great. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notes:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.

[source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

```
>>> struct.unpack('<BH', '\x01\x02\x03')
(1, 770)
>>> struct.unpack('>BH', '\x01\x02\x03')
(1, 515)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Just what I wanted.